# Custom Section initializer in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Xcode 12.3 | SwiftUI 2.0 | macOS 11

I'm trying to get a custom initializer to write this:

```
Section("TITLE") { ... content ... }
```

Instead of this:

```
Section(header: Text("TITLE") { ... content ... }
```

But I cannot create a custom initializer because `self.init`is not recognized:

```
extension Section { 
    init(_ title: String, @escaping () -> Content) { 
        self.init(........ <--- No autocompletions for self initializers
    }
}
```

I have the same problem with custom inits for Buttons.

Does anyone knows how to access to that initializers from extensions?

Comment: reference : https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/swiftui-extensions-using-generics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
extension Section where Parent == Text, Content: View, Footer == EmptyView {
    init(_ title: String, content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.init(header: Text(title), content: content)
    }
}
```

[On GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Extensions/Section%2B.swift)

Comment: How can I know what generic types are needed? `Parent`, `Content` and `Footer` per example.

Comment: see declaration of `struct Section`